# Saving 2d object array indicies to 1d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to search through a 2d object array and separate the objects based on an object class field, test 1 and test 2 respectively. I then want to write the 2d array's object's indices to two 1d arrays as x,y. I would like to have two pairs of two 1d arrays for each object, so that I can calculate the distance between the test 1 and test 2 object.

My problem/Question
When I run a loop on one of the 1d arrays to print their values to check them, they are filled with a bunch of zeros and they shouldn't be. I included comments in the code to help clarify.

```
public class gameboard2 {



public static void main(String[] args) {

Character2 objectArray[][] = new Character2[8][8];

int test1X1[] = new int[100];
int test1Y1[] = new int[100];
int test2X2[] = new int[100];
int test2Y2[] = new int[100];
int junkX1Array[] = new int[100];
int junkY1Array[] = new int[100];   



for (int row = 0; row < objectArray.length; row++){
for(int col = 0; col < objectArray.length; col++){
    if (row <= 1 && col <= 7){
    objectArray[row][col] = new Character2();
            objectArray[row][col].setType("Test1");
            objectArray[row][col].setIdTest1(row,col);
            objectArray[row][col].objectFlag = true;

     }
    else if ((row == 6 || row == 7) && (col <= 7)){
    objectArray[row][col]= new Character2();
            objectArray[row][col].setType("Test2");
    objectArray[row][col].setIdTest2(row,col);
            objectArray[row][col].objectFlag = true;


    }
    else {
    objectArray[row][col]= new Character2();
       objectArray[row][col].setType("Test3");

    }
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < objectArray.length; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < objectArray.length; y++ ){


    if (objectArray[x][y].getType().compareTo("Test1") == 0){
            test1X1[x] = x;
            test1Y1[y] = y;


    }

 if (objectArray[x][y].getType().compareTo("Test2") == 0){
        test2X2[x] = x;
        test2Y2[y] = y;

       System.out.println(test2X2[x]);
      //Arrays are filled with 2d array object indices and printed as they are filled. These values appear correct. However when you print from the array (see below) its filled with a bunch of zeros.
    }

    else
        junkX1Array[x] = x;
        junkY1Array[y] = y;
    }
    }
    System.out.print("Now the newly created array will be printed");
    // Array is printed. Values differ.
            for (int b = 0; b < test2X2.length; b++)
    {
        System.out.println(test2X2[b]);

    }

    }
}
```

//
    This is the object class.

```
public class Character2 {



private String id;
private String type;
boolean objectFlag = false;



public void setType(String AssignType) {
type = AssignType;
}
public String getType(){
return type;
}
public String getId(){
return id;
}


public void setIdTest1(int row, int col){
id = ("Test1" + " row: " + row + " col: " +  col);  

}
public void setIdTest2(int row, int col){
id = ("Test2" + " row: " + row + " col: " +  col);

}
}
```

Comment: Is the number of rows and columns equal in you objectArray?

Comment: Yes its 8 by 8                                                                                  Character objectArray[][] = new Character[8][8];

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to find the indices of the objects in my 2d object array and save them to 1 d arrays, x and y respectively, so I can calculate the distance between them.

Comment: @BurtReynolds That's fine. What is it that you are asking us, specifically?

Comment: You might need to clarify this. _It seems to be finding and separating the objects just find but, there are a bunch of zeros and what appears to be erroneous values (when I run a loop on them individually to print their values) being stored in the arrays_ It's working, but it's not working when you run the loop on **what** individually? How do you know they're erroneous?

Comment: When I run a loop on say test2X2 array to print the values it returns a bunch of zeros along with what should be some of the correct indices mixed in and I am wondering why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an actual [mcve], your code block is almost useless. For instance what happens if an element's type isn't `"test1"` or `"test2"`? Your distance formula also looks flawed, the Pythagorean Theorem is `(A*A) + (B*B) = (C*C)`.

Comment: It looks you want a pairing function https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function . It is sort of like pointers, but in math - you can find an index for every collection of ints, and then given the ondex you can rebuild original collection

Comment: `objectArray[x][y].getType().compareTo("test1")` I assume is supposed to return true or any non-zero positive integer if it matches. So why do you go in the condition when it does not match the type `objectArray[x][y].getType().compareTo("test1") == 0`? It should be `objectArray[x][y].getType().compareTo("test1") == 1/*true*/`.

Comment: @Falla Coulibaly Sorry, that's not right. Check [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) _Returns:_ 
    _a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object._

Comment: I'm going to go with John Henly, we need a complete code sample

Comment: I added more of the code and thanks for your help.

Comment: Any way to make this a complete code sample? As in, I can copy and paste and it will run?

Comment: Sure, this should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Mast.mangesh was correct, he just didn't have the full context. You are indexing into your test arrays with x and y but you aren't adding values to your test arrays at every x and y. They should have their own index that is incremented only when you add something to the test array itself, which brings me to my next suggestion. Why are you using arrays here? Why not use something more robust, like ArrayList? You would have avoided that all along...

```
public static void test(){
    Character2 objectArray[][] = new Character2[8][8];
    ArrayList<Integer> x1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> y1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> x2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> y2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> junkx = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> junky = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int row = 0; row < objectArray.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < objectArray.length; col++){
            if (row <= 1 && col <= 7){
                objectArray[row][col] = new Character2();
                objectArray[row][col].setType("Test1");
                objectArray[row][col].setIdTest1(row,col);
                objectArray[row][col].objectFlag = true;

             }
             else if ((row == 6 || row == 7) && (col <= 7)){
                objectArray[row][col]= new Character2();
                objectArray[row][col].setType("Test2");
                objectArray[row][col].setIdTest2(row,col);
                objectArray[row][col].objectFlag = true;
             }
             else {
                objectArray[row][col]= new Character2();
                objectArray[row][col].setType("Test3");

             }
        }
    }
    for(Character2[] c2: objectArray){
        for(Character2 c: c2){
            System.out.print(" " + c.getType() );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < objectArray.length; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < objectArray.length; y++ ){
            if (objectArray[x][y].getType().compareTo("Test1") == 0){
                x1.add(x);
                y1.add(y);
            }

            if (objectArray[x][y].getType().compareTo("Test2") == 0){
                x2.add(x);
                y2.add(y);
            }
            else{ 
                junkx.add(x);
                junky.add(y);
            } 
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Now the newly created array will be printed");
    for(int i : y2){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try. I have only been programming for a few weeks. I didn't know about ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help this works and I learned something new.

Comment: Glad it helped. Keep on coding! If you're only a few weeks in, check out codeacademy.com they do a pretty good job on the introductions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are using a same index(x, y) for test1x1, test1Y1, test2X2, test2Y2 arrays. try using different index name for those arrays. because I think they are 4 different arrays.
for example :

```
int i=0;j=0;k=0;l=0;
for (int x = 0; x < objectArray.length; x++){
for (int y = 0; y < objectArray.length; y++ ){

if (objectArray[x][y].getType().compareTo("test1") == 0){
        test2X2[i] = x;
        test2Y2[j] = y;
       i++;j++;
}

if (objectArray[x][y].getType().compareTo("test2") == 0){
        test1X1[k] = x;
        test1Y1[l] = y;
      k++;l++;
}}}
```

Comment: If this were the problem he wouldn't be getting a bunch of 0s littered throughout his arrays.

Comment: My bad, @Mast.mangesh. you are correct. I didn't understand at first what you were saying.

Comment: Thanks I see what you're saying.